# setting twitter gem not to send tweets on my dev and test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, heroku, development-environment, production-environment

How do I set up my twitter gem not to send tweets in my dev and test environment?

Also I am using Heroku and I don't know how to tell heroku which app is a test which is the prod ...

I followed your tips and added this in my code:

```
      if Rails.env.staging? 
        Notifier.send_email(msg)
      elsif Rails.env.production?
        Twitter.update(msg)
      else
        logger.info "JOEL - #msg}"
        Notifier.send_email(msg)
      end
```

For whatever reason, although I set RACK_ENV= staging and created staging.rb in my environment folder ... I still never managed to get Rails.env.staging?  = true ...

I am almost there,  but not quite...

any tips,

Joel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to Vibhu's answer...

You need to wrap the code in this

```
if Rails.env.production?
  # Code here will only execute in your production environment
end
```

And then you need to specify a different environment on Heroku for your Heroku testing / dev server so it knows not to send anything on that specific Heroku server: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments

Comment: hey I follow your tips and the doc but I am still facing a minor problem. I don't manage to get Rails.env.staging? to true when in my staging environment. See my original posting, I've added the code I am using ... cheers, joel

Comment: Did you restart the server?  `heroku restart --app app_name_here`

Answer (score 2):

Are you on Rails 3? You can always wrap any code that you only want to execute in one environment like this:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  #Code here will only execute in your production (Heroku) environment
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem? with Heroku. But you should set both your RACK_ENV and your RAILS_ENV config variables to staging.